# Could someone explain why my last else statement will not run?

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50, argv, atoi

I'm trying to convert my argv string into an integer. For some, I can't get my last else statement to run. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm just starting with C. Here is my code.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        for(int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(argv[1][i])) {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            
            }
            
        }
    }
        else if (argc != 2)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        }
        
        else if (argc == 2)
        {
            int x = atoi(argv[1]);
            printf("%i", x);
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Written with braces and indentation, your code structure is like this:

```
if ( argc == 2 )
{
     stuff
}
else
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
         stuff
    }
    else if ( argc == 2 )
    {
         stuff
    }
}
```

So once the first test fails, execution jumps to after the end of the block controlled by the corresponding `else` .

The code you wrote has the same logic just omitted optional braces and different whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get my last else statement to run.
> ... why my last else statement will not run?

With better formatting, it might be easier to see that code is testing `(argc == 2)` twice in the same `if, else if, else if` tree.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
  if (argc == 2) {
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++) {
      if (!isdigit(argv[1][i])) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");

      }

    }
  } else if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
  } else if (argc == 2) {  // cannot be true given prior `if (argc == 2)`
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%i", x);
    return 0;
  }
}
```